# Find the value of $P(1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> Let $P (x) = x^2 + bx + c$, where $b$ and $c$ are integer.
>
> If $P(x)$ is a factor of both $x^4 + 6x^2 + 25$ and $3x^4 + 4x^2 + 28x
>  + 5$, find the value of $P(1)$.

I am not being able to solve this.Some hints/suggestions?

Tell me if I can edit to improve this question.I could'nt try much.Got stuck.

Comment: $x^4+6x^2+25=(x^2-2x+5)(x^2+2x+5)$, can you take it from there?

Comment: Looks promising @lulu ...trying!

Comment: **Hint** $\ p\mid f,g \iff p\mid \gcd(f,g).\ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT :

$P(x)$ is a factor of 
$$3x^4 + 4x^2 + 28x + 5-3(x^4 + 6x^2 + 25)=-14(x^2-2x+5)$$